# Testing overlapping curves using an integral?

Tags: calculus

Taking any two closed curves given by parametric equations $(x(t),y(t))$, one can approximate them with polygons with a large numbers of sides.

To see if the shapes intersect, I can divide the curves into sectors, or triangles, and check if a vertex from the other polygon is inside this triangle.

If any vertices from one polygon is inside the sectors of the other then the shapes  intersect. Making the number of the sides of the polygon go to infinity, it seems like I should be able to express this condition as an integral, perhaps using dirac-delta functions.

Any idea how to go about this? Equally one could check if any of the sides of one polygon intersect the sides of the other. My immediate thought is:

$$\int \int \delta( f(x(t_1),x(t_1+\delta t),x'(t_2),x(t_2+\delta t_2) ) ) dt_1 dt_2 >0$$

where $f(a,b,c,d)$ is a line intersection test between line segments $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$ which is $0$ if the lines intersect.